# Chrome high processor usage on Asus Tuf A15

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, asus

When I start the laptop, being it from Hibernate, Shutdown, or do a Restart, on launching the chrome, Chrome.exe starts taking 50% of processor usage and laptop fans go crazy. I had to manually kill the process "Chrome.exe" to free up the system. There is more than one same named process so chrome doesn't close and I continue with my work but this drains my battery really fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of a startup item window Update.vbs. Disable it and the problem is solved.

This script is somehow gets installed while installing a cracked software